# GDPR Module Installion "Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.01.1, 100.0.02]

Tags: magento2.2, composer, third-party-module, gdpr

I am trying ton install the following GDPR module via command line for Magento version 2.2.1 : https://github.com/AdfabConnect/magento2gdpr

However, the install fails and produces the below error message.

```
  Problem 1
- Conclusion: don't install magento/module-sales 100.2.0-rc20
- Installation request for adfab/m2-module-gdpr ^1.0 -> satisfiable by adfab/m2-module-gdpr[1.0.0].
- Conclusion: don't install magento/framework 101.0.1|install magento/module-sales 100.2.0-rc20
- Conclusion: remove magento/framework 101.0.1|install magento/module-sales 100.2.0-rc20
- adfab/m2-module-gdpr 1.0.0 requires magento/module-sales 100.* -> satisfiable by magento/module-sales[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.1.1, 100.0.10, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.0.11, 100.1.4, 100.0.12, 100.1.5, 100.0.13, 100.1.6, 100.0.14, 100.1.7, 100.2.0-rc20, 100.1.8, 100.0.15, 100.0.16, 100.1.9, 100.1.10].
- magento/module-sales 100.0.2 requires magento/framework 100.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.0.12, 100.0.13, 100.0.14, 100.0.15, 100.0.16, 100.0.17, 100.0.18, 100.0.19, 100.0.20].
- magento/module-sales 100.0.3 requires magento/framework 100.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.0.12, 100.0.13, 100.0.14, 100.0.15, 100.0.16, 100.0.17, 100.0.18, 100.0.19, 100.0.20].
- magento/module-sales 100.0.4 requires magento/framework 100.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.0.12, 100.0.13, 100.0.14, 100.0.15, 100.0.16, 100.0.17, 100.0.18, 100.0.19, 100.0.20].
- magento/module-sales 100.0.5 requires magento/framework 100.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.0.12, 100.0.13, 100.0.14, 100.0.15, 100.0.16, 100.0.17, 100.0.18, 100.0.19, 100.0.20].
- magento/module-sales 100.0.6 requires magento/framework 100.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.0.12, 100.0.13, 100.0.14, 100.0.15, 100.0.16, 100.0.17, 100.0.18, 100.0.19, 100.0.20].
- magento/module-sales 100.0.7 requires magento/framework 100.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.0.12, 100.0.13, 100.0.14, 100.0.15, 100.0.16, 100.0.17, 100.0.18, 100.0.19, 100.0.20].
- magento/module-sales 100.0.8 requires magento/framework 100.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.0.12, 100.0.13, 100.0.14, 100.0.15, 100.0.16, 100.0.17, 100.0.18, 100.0.19, 100.0.20].
- magento/module-sales 100.0.9 requires magento/framework 100.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.0.12, 100.0.13, 100.0.14, 100.0.15, 100.0.16, 100.0.17, 100.0.18, 100.0.19, 100.0.20].
- magento/module-sales 100.0.10 requires magento/framework 100.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.0.12, 100.0.13, 100.0.14, 100.0.15, 100.0.16, 100.0.17, 100.0.18, 100.0.19, 100.0.20].
- magento/module-sales 100.0.11 requires magento/framework 100.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.0.12, 100.0.13, 100.0.14, 100.0.15, 100.0.16, 100.0.17, 100.0.18, 100.0.19, 100.0.20].
- magento/module-sales 100.0.12 requires magento/framework 100.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.0.12, 100.0.13, 100.0.14, 100.0.15, 100.0.16, 100.0.17, 100.0.18, 100.0.19, 100.0.20].
- magento/module-sales 100.0.13 requires magento/framework 100.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.0.12, 100.0.13, 100.0.14, 100.0.15, 100.0.16, 100.0.17, 100.0.18, 100.0.19, 100.0.20].
- magento/module-sales 100.0.14 requires magento/framework 100.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.0.12, 100.0.13, 100.0.14, 100.0.15, 100.0.16, 100.0.17, 100.0.18, 100.0.19, 100.0.20].
- magento/module-sales 100.0.15 requires magento/framework 100.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.0.12, 100.0.13, 100.0.14, 100.0.15, 100.0.16, 100.0.17, 100.0.18, 100.0.19, 100.0.20].
- magento/module-sales 100.0.16 requires magento/framework 100.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.2, 100.0.3, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9, 100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.0.12, 100.0.13, 100.0.14, 100.0.15, 100.0.16, 100.0.17, 100.0.18, 100.0.19, 100.0.20].
- magento/module-sales 100.1.0-rc1 requires magento/framework 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 100.1.12].
- magento/module-sales 100.1.0-rc2 requires magento/framework 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 100.1.12].
- magento/module-sales 100.1.0-rc3 requires magento/framework 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 100.1.12].
- magento/module-sales 100.1.0 requires magento/framework 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 100.1.12].
- magento/module-sales 100.1.1 requires magento/framework 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 100.1.12].
- magento/module-sales 100.1.2 requires magento/framework 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 100.1.12].
- magento/module-sales 100.1.3 requires magento/framework 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 100.1.12].
- magento/module-sales 100.1.4 requires magento/framework 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 100.1.12].
- magento/module-sales 100.1.5 requires magento/framework 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 100.1.12].
- magento/module-sales 100.1.6 requires magento/framework 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 100.1.12].
- magento/module-sales 100.1.7 requires magento/framework 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 100.1.12].
- magento/module-sales 100.1.8 requires magento/framework 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 100.1.12].
- magento/module-sales 100.1.9 requires magento/framework 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 100.1.12].
- magento/module-sales 100.1.10 requires magento/framework 100.1.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.0-rc1, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0, 100.1.1, 100.1.2, 100.1.3, 100.1.4, 100.1.5, 100.1.6, 100.1.7, 100.1.8, 100.1.9, 100.1.10, 100.1.11, 100.1.12].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.0.2].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.0.3].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.0.4].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.0.5].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.0.6].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.0.7].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.0.8].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.0.9].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.0-rc1].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.0-rc2].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.0-rc3].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.0].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.0.10].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.0.11].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.1].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.0.12].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.2].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.3].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.0.13].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.4].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.0.14].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.5].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.0.15].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.6].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.7].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.0.16].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.0.17].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.8].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.9].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.0.18].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.0.19].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.10].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.11].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.0.20].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[101.0.1, 100.1.12].
- Installation request for magento/framework (locked at 101.0.1) -> satisfiable by magento/framework[101.0.1].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Does this require a composer update to install successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because probably packagist is not updated with the last module version that you see on github. If you run "composer require adfab/m2-module-gdpr" this will fetch the module from the packagist repository.

Instead of pulling the module from packagist, try to add it manually as a vcs (private repository) to your composer.json.

Inside the repositories include the github link like this example:

```
"repositories": [

        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/AdFabConnect/magento2gdpr.git"
    }
],
```

In the require section add it like that:

```
    "require": {
    "magento/product-community-edition": "2.2.1",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",

    "adfab/m2-module-gdpr": "dev-master"
},
```

Note: in this example im installing dev-master. You can install the version you prefer.

Add the dependencies as well in require dev:

```
"require-dev": {

    "fzaninotto/faker": "*",
    "magento/module-customer": "*",
    "magento/module-quote": "*",
    "magento/module-sales": "*",
    "sabas/edifact": "*"
},
```

All you have to do now is run:

```
composer update
bin/magento setup:upgrade --keep-generated
bin/magento cache:clean
```

The message after running the composer update should look like that:

[image: composer update]

Let me know if this work for you.